# How do I install PostgreSQL on a Payara Docker container?

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, jdbc, payara

I'm trying to install create a container that runs a Payaraserver with my JAX-RS application. Getting the server running wasn't too hard, I simply used the official image. However, when I create the Connection Pool I was not able to ping, and I got this error message:

```
Ping Connection Pool failed for PostgreSQLPool. 
Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for :
 org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource Please check the server.log for more details.
```

Also, when i tried to upload the .war file (after I had created the DataSource) I got this error message:

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 
2.7.7.payara-p3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: 
org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource Error Code:
 0. Please see server.log for more details.
```

After a bit of digging I thought that the problem was that I did not have the postgre jdbc driver in the container. I created this Dockerfile:

```
FROM payara/server-full

COPY postgresql-42.2.18.jar /opt/payara41/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib
```

, which I thought would add the .jar file to the container. Unfortunately, no change was made. I have the exact same configurations on a local installation of Payara and everything works just fine there.

Is there something that I'm missing? I'm quite new to dockers, so if someone would be able to pint me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What's your version of Payara Server? For the latest version 5.2020.5, you need to copy the postgresql JAR to `/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib`.

Comment: I found the answer to my question. I was copying it to domain1, but on the Docker image you should copy it to the production domain